# Is my thinking correct? Python conditional keylogger

Tags: python-3.x, keylogger

Total python newb - some inappropriateness might follow.

My situation:

I'm trying to make myself a keylogger, that would log my keystrokes to different places depending on the software I'm using (a pet project for my shortcut usage tracking and optimization). I have the keylogging figured out, and I can get the name of the currently active window, but I can't find a way to connect them together in a simple way.
My current thinking is that the program needs to be checking what's the currently active window every second or so and depending on the result, using conditional statements to log the keystrokes into different .txt's. The problem is that a keystroke listener is a loop of its own and I can only be executing one or another.
Here's a [paste of my current code](https://pastebin.com/fCMGddJq) if you'd like to check it out.

```
 #later to be changed to other condition i.e. while True:
i=0
while i<15:
    i += 1
    soft = get_current_window(soft)
    if soft == "sublime_text.exe":
        #log everything to some one place
        print("sublime")
    if soft == "chrome.exe":
        #log everything to some other place
        print("chrome")

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

My questions:

Is my thinking about the process correct? Would you do anything differently?
Do I need to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) right about now or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Do you actually want to learn Python or create a nasty key-logger? :P I'm not sure if it's ethical to help you :P

Comment: :D you see right through me. I'm a pro at wasting time doing obnoxious projects of questionable value and now that you know this - it's all up to you:P